# How to visualize longitudinal data?

Tags: visualization, survey, longitudinal

I am trying to graph some survey data. We collected survey data where each survey was asked twice per day for 30 days to the same approximately 20 people. So in my data, I have the same people on different rows, multiple times. The variable I am currently trying to visualize was about the first bus route that they took (for one of their twice daily trips). So I want to be able to see which bus route they took, on which day, and which user they are. I tried many different things so far, but nothing is giving me an effective and easy to understand graph. 
Earlier I tried this:

```
t_1_bus_route_taken <- ethica_surveys_filter_final %>%
group_by(Name, pre_post) %>%
filter(!is.na(first_bus_route_taken))

ggplot(t_1_bus_route_taken, aes(x=response_time, 
y=first_bus_route_taken, group=Name)) + 
+   geom_line(colour="grey70") + 
+   geom_point(aes(colour=Name), size=4) + 
+   facet_grid(Name ~ .) +
+   scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

But it didn't look right. I also tried this:

```
ggplot() + 
+   geom_line(data=t_1_bus_route_taken, aes(x=response_time, 
y=first_bus_route_taken, group=Name, 
color=first_bus_route_taken), size=0.8, alpha=0.05)
```

The graph was really busy and hard to read. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: How is _an effective and easy to understand graph_ defined?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that. I meant something that is not too busy and can be easily visualized.